# How to find the source video size using VMR9 renderless mode

Tags: directx, directshow

My application uses VMR9 Renderless mode to play a WMV file.  I build a filter graph with **IGraphBuilder::RenderFile** and control playback with **IMediaControl**.  Everything plays okay, but I can't figure out how to determine the source video size.  Any ideas?

Note: This question was asked before in [How can I adjust the video to a specified size in VMR9 renderless mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4989273/195123). But the solution was to use Windowless mode instead of Renderless mode, which would require rewriting my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you want the Video renderer.  You can do this by using EnumFilters on the IGraphBuilder interface.  Then call EnumPins on that filter to find the input pin.  You can then call ConnectionMediaType to get the media type being fed into that filter.  Now depending what formattype is set to you can cast the pbFormat pointer to the relevant structure and from there find out what the video size is.  If you want the size before that (to see if some scaling is going on) you can work your way back across the pin using "ConnectedTo" to get the next filter back.  You can then find its input pins and repeat the ConnectionMediaType call.  Repeat until you get to the filter's pin that you want.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  It took awhile, but I was able to figure out how to find my source video by navigating through the filter graph.  I was hoping there would be an easier way to accomplish this, but it seems to be the only way--at least in Renderless mode.

Comment: @Knute: Nothing is easy where DirectShow is concerned .. its flexible as hell but the sooner it dies the better in my opinion.

Comment: Sadly Media Foundation is even worse.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the MediaInfo project at http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/hr/Download/Windows and through the CS wrapper included in the VCS2010 or VCS2008 folders get all the information about a video you need.

EDIT: Sorry I thought you were on managed. But in either case the MediaInfo can be used, so maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Using a library like this certainly has the potential to be much easier than navigating through the filter graph.